# How does browserify bundle a universal module

Tags: browserify, umd

I know browserify can consume UMD modules by means of transforms, but when I want to build a lib using browserify, how can I build an UMD module? Is there any transform I can use?

Comment: What does "browserify can consume UMD modules by means of transforms" mean?

Comment: `deamdify` like this transform allows you to use AMD module with browserify

Comment: Right, but you shouldn't need any transform to use a *UMD* module with browserify, although you may need to `noParse` it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to build a UMD module with browserify use the `standalone` option. Like:

```
browserify('./entry.js', {
  standalone: 'moduleName',
})
```

Comment: isn't it that `standalone` exposes the module to global namespace?

Comment: `standalone` creates a UMD module. If the code doesn't detect that it's in an AMD or CommonJS environment, it sets a global variable.

Answer (score 4):

From the CLI: `browserify -s NameOfModule`

This creates a standalone module exposed under the name of your choosing.

Utilize by loading the output file in a browser and access via `window.NameOfModule`, or see RequireJS docs on how to use it that way.

Comment: Also, JMM's comment is also correct, and is a way you'd configure it in a build script.